# Converting jQuery parent() and siblings() calls to pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble, the site I'm working on is having a conflict with jQuery and I have no clue how to convert this to Javascript, or whether it is even possible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div.links').parent('td').siblings().find('a.schedule')
});
```

Comment: is `$('.schedule')` not sufficient to find these elements? If so, then you can just use `document.getElementsByClassName('schedule');`

Comment: I should have explained it better...there are two columns in the table.  Column A and Column B.

All the links I want to select in Column B have class "schedule" but I only want to grab the links in Column B where Column A has a div with class "links".  (In reality it's somethinglike supersaverLinks, but i shortened it for brevity).  This div only appears for certain rows, and that's why I want to only select the link in Column B conditionally.

Comment: Did you consider https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ instead of removing jQuery? Maybe that would allow you to both resolve conflict and use jQuery/don't refactor too much?

Comment: You didn't need to explain 'better,' though it's appreciated; what you should have done is show us the code. For guidance, see the [MCVE] guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is verbose, but JS verbosity is one reason we all love jQuery:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('links');

var hrefs = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i )
  {
    var n = links[i];
    var pn = n.parentNode;
    
    if (n.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td')
      {
        var sib = n.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
        if (sib && sib.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td')
          {
            var as = sib.getElementsByClassName('schedule');
            
            for ( var j = 0; j < as.length; ++j )
              hrefs.push(as[j]);
          }
      }     
  }

// highlight what we've found
for ( i = 0; i < hrefs.length; ++i )
  hrefs[i].className = 'selected';
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="links">links</div></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="schedule">schedule</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="schedule">schedule</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="links">links</div></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="schedule">schedule</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="links">links</div></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="schedule">schedule</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="schedule">schedule</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```